# Is virtual reality a contradiction?

Tags: contradiction

When you consider the word "virtual" you would usually picture something that is simulated or exists in a computational manner.

Does this mean that virtual reality is actually contradictory? After all, reality is literally reality.

Comment: I don't have time to add a definition for "virtual" at the moment, so please feel free to do so.

Comment: Take "the blue pill" to stay in virtual reality.

Comment: I sometimes feel like I'm a brain in a vat. Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy? :/

Answer (score 3):

It is an ***oxymoron*** which by definition (see below), is composed of ***apparently** contradictory terms*.

So yes, you are right to an extent when you consider the usual meanings of the separate words. However, they have **alternative meanings** (to be used in this context) which make *virtual reality* **not** such a contraction after all.

From **oxforddictionaries.com**:

> [**virtual**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/virtual): ADJECTIVE
>
> **2** *[Computing] Not physically existing as such but made by software to
> appear to do so*: virtual images
>
> See also ***virtual reality***.
>
> More example sentences:
>
> Once they figured out how to get Trojans onto computer, creating their
> own virtual spamming super computer, spammers have adopted this method
> for most of the spam they send out.
>
> This paper explores the potential for developing virtual dissection
> software for physical collaboration.
>
> The software also supports multiple virtual desktops.
>
> [**reality**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reality):
> *NOUN*
>
> **1.3** *The quality of being lifelike*: the reality of Marryat’s detail
>
> More example sentences:
>
> Harsh reality is created with striking clarity throughout the
> collection, leaving the reader both awed and dismayed.
>
> He loved acting and the people that were in it and that could produce
> and create moments of great reality.
>
> Only when films regain the sparks of creativity, originality and
> reality, will we see crowds in cinema halls again.
>
> **[virtual reality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/virtual-reality)**: *NOUN*
>
> The computer-generated simulation of a three-dimensional image or
> environment that can be interacted with in a seemingly real or
> physical way by a person using special electronic equipment, such as a
> helmet with a screen inside or gloves fitted with sensors.
>
> Example sentences:
>
> You play as a character that has entered a computer system in virtual
> reality to destroy a virus infecting the main frame.
>
> As virtual reality simulators are computer based systems they generate
> output data, or what is commonly referred to as metrics.
>
> Their aim is simple: to generate a truly immersive virtual reality
> environment that has a useful commercial function.
>
> [**oxymoron**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oxymoron):   *NOUN*
>
> *A figure of speech in which apparently contradictory terms appear in
> conjunction* (e.g. faith unfaithful kept him falsely true).
>
> **Example** sentences:
>
> Yes, but it does leave a reader ever more certain that the term ‘mature male’ is an oxymoron.
>
> One day I sat her down to explain to her the word *oxymoron* and then
> to describe a *magnificent and bucolic world of insults*.
>
> The idea of a *light of darkness* is certainly an *oxymoron*,
> certainly *a contradiction in terms*, and yet we find that among
> various mystics.

Comment: How does this compare to a [paradox](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326773/what-is-the-word-describing-impossible-phenomenon-such-as-this-page-is-intent)?

Answer (score 2):

> **virtual** -  very close to being something without actually being it; existing or occurring on computers or on the Internet; being on or simulated on a computer or computer network
>
> **virtual reality** - an artificial environment which is experienced through sensory stimuli (as sights and sounds) provided by a computer and in which one's actions partially determine what happens in the environment

Going by these definitions, I would not call it a contradiction at all.

Reality is not simulated.  It is our conscious world—what really exists.   Virtual experience would be a simulation, that is, a representation of reality.  So going by this, "virtual reality" is like saying "artificial reality".  Maybe even "turkey bacon" ;)

On the other hand, reality as we know it could be computerized—if you believe in *The Matrix*

Comment: +1 for the definitions, but I think the term '*artificial* reality' detracts from the clarity of the definitions. Although it is by definition *artificial* if it *isn't* reality, your initial emphasis on the *closeness* to reality gives a better sense of the word *virtual* in the question's context.

Comment: True; it's "mock-reality".  Close, but no cigar.  Virtual reality is basically a world for those who want to escape reality.  It is like a parallel universe on a computer.

Comment: @RoyC, can you add the source/citation of the definitions?

Comment: @alwayslearning http://www.merriam-webster.com/